# Deactivate layout update with module deactivation in magento

Tags: magento, layout, module

i'm programming a magento module. I've been wondering, how to deactivate layout updates of my module, by deactivating the module. I wan't to deliver the possibility to recover all changes done by the module if it's inactive.

Here's my **config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

    <modules>
        <Bss_Tierpreis>
            <version>0.0.5</version>
        </Bss_Tierpreis>
    </modules>

    <global>

        <models>
            <tierpreis>
                <class>Bss_Tierpreis_Model</class>
            </tierpreis>
        </models>

        <blocks>
            <tierpreis>
                <class>Bss_Tierpreis_Block</class>
            </tierpreis>
        </blocks>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <tierpreis>
                    <file>tierpreis.xml</file>
                </tierpreis>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

**tierpreis.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss">
                <name>css/tierpreis.css</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content"> 
            <reference name="alert.urls"> 
                <block type="tierpreis/getlist" name="tierpreis_getlist" template="tierpreis/list.phtml" />
            </reference>
        </reference>   
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

It's annoying that the css file is loaded while he module is not active. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Did you disable that module in System->Configuration->Advanced? If then, please clear the cache after that module was disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ifconfig parameter

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="module/general/enabled">
   <template>route/to/template</template>
 </action>
</reference>
```

You need to set one dropdown for module enable/disable in yourmodule in admin panel and set its value is "0" => "No" then save it and add path this in layout file ifconfig parameter.